# How to install Trust SC-5500p USB 5.1 external sound card?

Tags: drivers, sound, usb, pulseaudio

(I use Ubuntu 14.04 64bit and the sound card is not broken as it works fine on Windows)

According to most of the reports online installing SC-5500p on Ubuntu seemed to be a cinch for most of the time. Some report that it even worked plug and play. At the end the day it can be said pretty safely that SC-5500p is built on standard audio drivers.

The following seems to be a more detailed version of what the GUI sound manager offers me (no Trust here):

```
$> cat /proc/asound/cards

 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7410000 irq 47
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xf6080000 irq 17
 2 [Device         ]: USB-Audio - USB Sound Device
                      USB Sound Device at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, full speed
```

---

The following is the output of `lsusb -v` which regards devices featuring the "Trust". The details of the second entry (after "[...]") is actually leaving no doubt that the referred to device is the SC-5500p.

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 15d9:0a4f Trust International B.V. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x15d9 Trust International B.V.
  idProduct          0x0a4f 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                1  USB OPTICAL MOUSE
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    [...]

Bus 003 Device 003: ID 145f:0143 Trust 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x145f Trust
  idProduct          0x0143 
  bcdDevice            0.10
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                2 USB Sound Device
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    [...]
```

---

As suggested [here](http://tuxanddroid.de/linux/trust-sc-5500p-externe-5-1-soundkarte-unter-linux) I altered `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` to feature the following two settings - but to no avail:

```
default-sample-channels = 6
enable-lfe-remixing = yes
```

Content of /etc/pusle/daemon.conf:

```
; daemonize = no
; fail = yes
; allow-module-loading = yes
; allow-exit = yes
; use-pid-file = yes
; system-instance = no
; local-server-type = user
; enable-shm = yes
; shm-size-bytes = 0 # setting this 0 will use the system-default, usually 64 MiB
; lock-memory = no
; cpu-limit = no

; high-priority = yes
; nice-level = -11

; realtime-scheduling = yes
; realtime-priority = 5

; exit-idle-time = 20
; scache-idle-time = 20

; dl-search-path = (depends on architecture)

; load-default-script-file = yes
; default-script-file = /etc/pulse/default.pa

; log-target = auto
; log-level = notice
; log-meta = no
; log-time = no
; log-backtrace = 0

resample-method = speex-float-1
; enable-remixing = yes
enable-lfe-remixing = yes 

flat-volumes = no

; rlimit-fsize = -1
; rlimit-data = -1
; rlimit-stack = -1
; rlimit-core = -1
; rlimit-as = -1
; rlimit-rss = -1
; rlimit-nproc = -1
; rlimit-nofile = 256
; rlimit-memlock = -1
; rlimit-locks = -1
; rlimit-sigpending = -1
; rlimit-msgqueue = -1
; rlimit-nice = 31
; rlimit-rtprio = 9
; rlimit-rttime = 1000000

; default-sample-format = s16le
; default-sample-rate = 44100
; alternate-sample-rate = 48000
default-sample-channels = 6
; default-channel-map = front-left,front-right

default-fragments = 8
default-fragment-size-msec = 10

; enable-deferred-volume = yes
deferred-volume-safety-margin-usec = 1
; deferred-volume-extra-delay-usec = 0
```

---

In conjunction with installation of other USB devices on Ubuntu it is sometimes mentioned that `/etc/modules` has to be extended with a line telling the kernel to load drivers or something. Currently `/etc/modules` just contains two lines:

```
> cat /etc/modules

lp
rtc
```

---

See "card2" in the end. I guess this is again my Trust device:

```
> sudo aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Device [USB Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the device **was** detected (as above transcripts show) but Pulse didn't *recognize* it.

[Then I executed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure):

```
killall pulseaudio
pulseaudio -k
```

and now it works - **even** when the device has not been plugged-in prior to booting.

At the end of the day its worth giving above two commands a try and see if that does the trick already.